# Weight Units- Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

In our store, we are using different units like LB's, OZ's, grams, kgs and etc.,

Right now we are using the configurable product for products for displaying with option weights. But the thing is default weight, how we consider the units for weight?

For suppose we have 5000lbs for Rice and 1000kg for Dals. How to view consider the weight unit for a different product?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correct, your question is how to setup a product weight that will reflect multiple units that you have, right?

The weight attribute in a product does not use any specific unit (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747444/magento-product-weight-unit) and [Magento documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-simple.html)). It is just a number that will be used for shipping calculations. So the real question is: **what unit are you using to calculate your shipping?** Then you need to convert your weight to be consistent across all products.

Using your example, suppose you have 2 products:

- Dals: 1000kg
- Rice: 5000lbs

and suppose your shipping carrier uses kg to calculate the shipping price.

In this case, since your shipping needs kg as a unit, your products should have the following weight:

- Dals: 1000 (because this is already in kg)
- Rice: 2267.962 (5000 lbs converted to kg)

Magento will not convert this for you (as far as I know), so you need to make the conversion by yourself.

Comment: My store in India, so my default weight KGS. UPS for USA shipping, what i need to do with "Weight Unit"   KGS or LBS?